# JSF with RMI tutorial

Tags: java, jsf, web-applications, rmi

I have to implement RMI with a JSF application, but I haven't found any tutorials on how to integrate these two technologies. I have very little experience with Java, only one simple app developed with JSF so I'm still a beginner.

If you have knowledge of any links that might be useful please share, or tips if you can explain the main points I have to go over in order to structure/configure my project correctly.

Thank you in advance.

**Update:**

This is the project's requirements:

"Consider a distributed web application called “job-searching service”. The application should keep record of all job offers in the past year mentioning whether the job is already taken or not. A user should be able to post a job offer and search through the job offers either by a date or by categories.

When implementing this system using Distributed Objects technologies consider the following constraints:

1. A Remote Object should expose the “post jobs” system functionality, letting the user to add a job to the system.
2. A Remote Object should expose the “search jobs” functionality, which allows the user to search for jobs either by a date or by a category.
3. All job offers must have a job title, company name, deadline, contact details and job specification.

Your task:

Design, implement and test the distributed application using Java or .NET specific technologies. (RMI or .NET Remoting technologies are compulsory)"

Comment: It would be better to explain **why** you need to use RMI to connect with a Web Application (JSF is just a web framework), or better: post the actual problem and SO people will help you to get an answer.

Comment: I have to make a web application as a school project that integrates RMI. I will add the requirements to my post.

Comment: RMI & JSF as separate technologies don't have any dependencies on each other (that I'm aware of). Therefore, you have to get both of them working separately. Have you gotten the RMI bit working yet?

Answer (score 3):

There's no mystery on doing this. Remember that JSF managed beans are just Java classes, so the only thing here will be your application design. For doing this, you can have a (very) basic skeleton like this:

In the JSF Project:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class LoginBean {

    private String user;
    private String password;

    public LoginBean() {
    }

    //getters and setters...

    public String validateUser() {
        UserService userService = new UserService();
        if (userService.validateUser(user, password)) {
            return "success";
        }
        return "problems";
    }
}

public class UserService extends  {

    public UserService() {
    }

    public boolean validateUser(String user, String password) {
        //do the Java RMI client job here...
        boolean result = false;
        if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
            System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
        }
        try {
            String name = "UserServiceRMI";
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(args[0]);
            UserServiceRMI userServiceRMI = (UserServiceRMI) registry.lookup(name);
            result = userServiceRMI.validateUser(user, password);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //you can (and must) do a better error handling
            System.out.println("UserService exception:");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

In the RMI Server project:

```
public interface UserRMIService extends java.rmi.Remote {
    boolean validateUser(String user, String password) throws java.rmi.RemoteException;
}

public class UserService implements UserRMIService {

    public UserService() {
        super();
    }

    public boolean validateUser(String user, String password) {
        //do the user validation here...
        //check against the database or another way you want/need
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
            System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
        }
        try {
            String name = "UserRMIService";
            UserRMIService engine = new UserService();
            UserRMIService stub =
                (UserRMIService) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(engine, 0);
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
            registry.rebind(name, stub);
            System.out.println("UserService bound");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //you can (and must) do a better error handling
            System.out.println("UserService exception:");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```